# Javafx error when closing stage in for loop

Tags: java, javafx

I'm getting an error that I cannot explain when executing this code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;

import java.util.List;


public class CSSDemoApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 300, 200);
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        borderPane.setTop(menuBar);
        Menu file = new Menu("File");
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("Close");
        menuItem.setOnAction(this::onClose);
        file.getItems().add(menuItem);
        menuBar.getMenus().add(file);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Demo Application");
        stage.show();
    }

    public void onClose(ActionEvent ae) {
        List<Window> openWindows = Stage.getWindows().filtered(window -> window.isShowing());
        for (Window window : openWindows) {
            // The line that throws the error
            window.hide();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The error is thrown by `window.hide();` line. Here is the error:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>   java.util.NoSuchElementException  at
>   java.base/java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:377)  at
>   javafx.example.CSSDemoApplication.onClose(CSSDemoApplication.java:39)
>     at
>   javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
>     at
>   javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>     at
>   javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>     at
>   javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>     at
>   javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>     at
>   javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
>     at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)     at
>   javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:465)
>     at
>   javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1380)
>     at
>   javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$12(ContextMenuContent.java:1333)
>     at
>   javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
>     at
>   javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>     at
>   javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>     at
>   javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>     at
>   javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>     at
>   javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>     at
>   javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
>     at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)     at
>   javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3851)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
>     at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)   at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
>     at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native
>   Method)   at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

If I replace

```
for (Window window : openWindows) {
     // The line that throws the error
     window.hide();
}
```

with

```
openWindows.get(0).hide();
```

it works fine. I have no clue why this behavior.

---

I'm using AdoptJdk 11 and Openjfx 11

Comment: technically, the error throws because you are changing the list while iterating over it. Not entirely certain what you want to achieve: hide all that are showing? Then why apply the filter at all?

Comment: Can you check what `openWindows.size()` returns? Maybe the first element of your ArrayList is totally fine, but you are looping and so if there is more than one it could error.

Comment: @kleopatra I get the error even without the filter. Basically I'm learning JavaFx and, as a task, I want to close all showing windows. Now I think I understand the error reason: `Stage.getWindows()` returns `ObservableList<Window>` which is a special kind of list  that tracks the changes. That's why the list get's modified while iterating following `hide` method call.

Comment: The javadoc states for `Window.getWindows`: *"Returns a list containing a reference to the currently showing JavaFX windows."* i.e. the filtering seems to already be done. If this was a "standard list", you'd get a `ConcurrentModificationException` for iterating through a list that has changed. This `ObservableList` implementation seems to throw a different error. You've already found one solution, but you could also just create a copy of the list: `for (Window window : new ArrayList<>(Window.getWindows())) {` I'd prefer your solution though (minus the filtering)...

Comment: I suspect `menuItem.setOnAction(e -> Platform.runLater(() -> onClose(null)));` would solve your problem.